After sorting a list LazyColumn recomposes, but right after that, recomposes again reverting the sort order
In my View composable I have a list of items in a LazyColumn and a "Sort" button that toggles between ascending and descending sort order. The list comes from my state holder class ViewComponent. This works fine.
I also have a "Search" button that retrieves data from a database that is then passed to View to replace the displayed data.
Although the data is replaced, the sort order is now broken: Whenever I press the "Sort" button the list is sorted and then instantly reverted back. I verified with println that the sort is actually executed as intended, but as soon as that finishes another recomposition seems to happen that resets the sort.
Is it possible that the function injectListFromDatabase is responsible for it? It only replaces the data class with the values from the database.
For clarity's sake I reduced my data classes to a bare minimum, but they actually have much more properties. The LazyColumn displays a list of GetToolsWithService objects:
data class GetToolsWithService(
    val id: Int,
)

data class ToolListState(
    val tools: List<GetToolsWithService>,
)

This is my View with the LazyColumn:
@Composable
fun View(
    component: ViewComponent = ViewComponent(),
    listFromDatabase: List<GetToolsWithService>,
) {
    if (listFromDatabase.isNotEmpty()) component.injectListFromDatabase(listFromDatabase)

    val stateList by component.stateList

    Button(onClick = {
        component.sort()
    }) {
        Text("Sort")
    }

    LazyColumn {
        items(stateList.tools) { Text("$it") }
    }
}

The stateholder:
class ViewComponent(
    private val sortTable: SortTable = SortTable(),
    initialListOfTools: List<GetToolsWithService> = List(10) { GetToolsWithService(it) },
) {
    val stateList: MutableState<ToolListState> = mutableStateOf(ToolListState(initialListOfTools))

    fun sort() {
        println("Sort Start")
        stateList.value = stateList.value.copy(tools = sortTable(stateList.value.tools))
        stateList.value.tools.forEach { println(it) }
        println("Sort end")
    }

    fun injectListFromDatabase(list: List<GetToolsWithService>) {
        stateList.value = stateList.value.copy(tools = list)
    }
}

And this is used for sorting:
enum class SortOrder {
    ASCENDING, DESCENDING
}

class SortTable(
    private var sortingOrderData: SortOrder = SortOrder.ASCENDING,
) {
    operator fun invoke(list: List<GetToolsWithService>): List<GetToolsWithService> =
        if (sortingOrderData == SortOrder.DESCENDING) {
            sortingOrderData = SortOrder.ASCENDING
            list.sortedBy { it.id }
        } else {
            sortingOrderData = SortOrder.DESCENDING
            list.sortedByDescending { it.id }
        }
}

The following is only used to emulate how the data from the database is passed to the View:
Column {
    var list: List<GetToolsWithService> by remember { mutableStateOf(emptyList()) }

    Button(onClick = {
        list = List(10) { GetToolsWithService(it + 100) } // "+100" so the items can be more easily distinguished
    }) { Text("Search") }

    View(
        listFromDatabase = list,
    )
}


This code is far from being runnable so we cannot reproduce it. Please provide a [mre].

Also it is important that you show us how injectListFromDatabase is called and what is passed for its parameter.

Its practically impossible for me to separate runnable code. I can only provide the whole code with database. I will try to create new public github project tomorrow.

Don't do that, the question must contain all relevant information itself. Do not provide links to your source code hosted on other sites. Instead provide all relevant code directly and remove everything that's not necessary. If you have trouble with that then create a new project and copy the code from your question to that new project. For every compile error decide if the part can be removed, otherwise add the minimal part of code so that it just compiles. It doesn't need to make sense, it just needs to compile. Then run the code and verify that the problem still persists. ...

... Then you can paste that code in the question. As far as I can tell we won't need the gradle files or import statements, just the composable that exhibits the problem and everything that's needed by that composable, like view models and data classes. Remember, don't use the code from your current project, use the code from your new dummy project that only contains the minimal version that is needed to reproduce the problem.

If you need data to fill your data structures just invent some dummy data. Fill a list with listOf(...), there is no need for any data layer code like database access, network requests and so on.

Please create a [mre]. It must not be long, just long enough to demonstrate the problem. Then paste it in the question. External links are not appropriate to share code that is relevant to the question.

I have edited my post to include a complete run-able code. I'm not capable of minimizing it further.

This is far away from being minimal. But it finally provides the essential information that I asked for in my first two comments. To cut things short I took the liberty and reduced the code so that it is now reasonably minimal. It is pretty close to what you had initially, I just added the parts that were necessary to reproduce the problem. This is something that you should have done yourself though, before even posting the question.

It took me some time to understand this code dump of yours, but that is not what StackOverflow is for: It focuses on providing solutions to problems, therefore only the shortest code that produces the problem is needed. Everything else just makes it harder for us to read, understand and answer your question. That is neither in your interest nor in ours. The [tour] mentions that StackOverflow aims to "build a library of detailed, high-quality answers". For that it is necessary that also the questions are high-quality. Please keep this in mind for future question you might want to ask.

The problem lies indeed with how you call injectListFromDatabase. On every (re-)composition this line of code is executed:
if (listFromDatabase.isNotEmpty()) component.injectListFromDatabase(listFromDatabase)

That doesn't hurt as long as the list is empty, but when "Search" was pressed this is not only executed once, it is repeated on every recomposition.
Let's take a look at what that means when "Sort" is pressed after "Search":

component.sort() is called and changes the stateList so it is now properly sorted. You already verified that by your println statements.
The change to stateList triggers a recomposition so View is executed again.
injectListFromDatabase is called. This replaces the content of stateList with listFromDatabase. Now, this means that the list we just sorted in 1. is never displayed, it is just thrown away and listFromDatabase is used instead.
If the "Sort" button is pressed again all of this repeats from 1., so nothing will ever change.

The problem is that injectListFromDatabase is not only called when listFromDatabase changes, it is also called on every other recomposition.
The fix is simple:
LaunchedEffect(listFromDatabase) {
    if (listFromDatabase.isNotEmpty()) component.injectListFromDatabase(listFromDatabase)
}

This wraps injectListFromDatabase in a lambda that is only executed when the LaunchedEffect's parameters change. I supplied listFromDatabase as the parameter, so this effectively skips the execution of injectListFromDatabase for each recomposition where listFromDatabase didn't change - as it is the case when the "Sort" button is pressed.
Sorting works now also after the "Search" button was pressed.

And it took me 8 hours to minimize my code, and it could be even smaller. Thank you, its just my second project, so I'm not good at making code that is easy to take parts out of it and i have only over 6000 lines of code. Again thanks for your help, I knew it will be something trivial and something to do with coroutines. For 7 days Ive tried to find a solution, but didn't remember LaunchedEffect exists.

I'm sorry it was so time-consuming for your, but StackOverflow just is no good fit for questions that are not clearly defined. For questions like these there is no way around having a minimal reproducible example. But I'm glad this worked out in the end, and perhaps it even helps you with future questions.

No I'm not complaining it took so long for me, it was a good experience, I'm happy my problem was resolved. I just hope it didn't take you long to shrink it even further. I tried to change listFromDatabase from mutableStateOf to only list, but i still don't understand why it recomposes everytime. Need to study Kotlin some more.

listFromDatabase never was a MutableState, it is a simple List parameter of the View composable. The additional recomposition occurs because injectListFromDatabase changes the MutableState stateList. Without the LaunchedEffect this change is on every recomposition (e.g. the sort button was pressed), with the LaunchedEffect it is only done when listFromDatabase changes. This is not Kotlin related, though, this is how Compose works.

So if I understand correctly, the condition if (listFromDatabase.isNotEmpty()) is tested every re-composition? And also I have tried to change LaunchedEffect for AtomicBoolean and it also works. I just needed to ensure the first if in View is run just once. So simple and I still didn't think of it for over 7 days.

Recomposition always encompasses the execution of the entire function, from start to end. When stateList changes, a recomposition of View is triggered and everything in there is executed again. if (listFromDatabase.isNotEmpty()) is the first thing that is executed (unless it is wrapped in a LaunchedEffect, of course).

So I understood it wrong from the beginning, I thought that only the things that has changed state get recomposed in a function. My thinking was if listFromDatabase does not change, if condition will not trigger. My bad from the beginning. Thanks for clarification.

It's still Kotlin code, you cannot only execute parts of a function, that's not a thing. What's special about Compose functions is that the Compose runtime keeps track of active composables and can call them whenever deemed necessary (called recomposition). During recomposition it can also skip calls to Compose functions whose parameters didn't change. But that only applies to Compose functions. if (listFromDatabase.isNotEmpty()) is not a Compose function so it gets executed on every recomposition. LaunchedEffect is a Compose function, so it gets skipped when its parameter is the same.

Again, thank you for this explanation. Now I understand how I made this mistake.
